# Socket recv - limited wait time

Tags: python, sockets

I am retrieving data from a server using `data = sock.recv(buffer_size)`. There are currently issues being experienced with the server (which I have no control over) resulting in occasional long wait times before receiving a response.

The response is usually almost instant resulting in me receiving the required data. However lately due to the server issue whenever there is a long wait time, I ultimately receive an error message back from the server. When that happens, I have to resend the same request.

My problem is that the `sock.recv()` call waits too long. What I need to do is only wait for data for a few seconds and if nothing is received I will resend the data request.

So my question is, can I somehow limit the amount of time `sock.recv()` waits for data? I do not want to kill the connection if I don't receive data in the specified time frame, I just want to know that the time limit has been reached so that I can do something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `socket.settimeout()` method

for more info visit http://docs.python.org/library/socket#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: `socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, timeout)` can be an option too. Less preferred in Python, but good to know when going to another language.